# Is this phrase correct, if yes, what does it mean?: "arise out of reason’s slumber"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Here is the full sentence:

> In the first three internationals as well as the Trotskyist one, the
>   absence of a positive Marxist understanding of the status of their
>   intellectuals is connected with the lack of a theory of leadership.
>   The monster of the absolute leadership, flanked by
>   anti-intellectualism, bureaucratism, and violence **arises out of
>   reason’s slumber** that fails to reflect this double absence.

From *Being a marxist* by Wolfgang Fritz Haug

Comment: If "reason" (nounification / personification of the ability of human being to think things through logically) figuratively ***slumbers, goes to sleep*** (if people don't ***use*** their powers of reasoning), this leads to violence (violence ***will arise*** if people cease to apply critical thinking to their circumstances).

Comment: ...note that the writer claims that people are failing to employ reason in respect of two things (it's a ***double** absence*), but it's not clear to me exactly what those two things actually ***are***. I'm sure *one* of them is "absolute leadership" (more specifically, not having a strong negative reaction against absolute leadership indicates that people are not applying *reason* to the situation). But the *other* "absence"? Probably it's the "combined" concept of being surrounded by anti-intellectuals ***and*** bureaucrats , but I think the text is a bit "woolly" in this respect.

Comment: (I have ***no idea*** why the writer chose to use ***bureaucratism*** rather than [the standard term](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bureaucratism%2Cbureaucracy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbureaucratism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbureaucracy%3B%2Cc0) ***bureaucracy***. But so far as I'm concerned, all it says to me is he's just not a very competent writer.)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I've added part of the previous sentences. I think that now the double absence is clear: Marxist understanding and theory of leadership? Could be the monster the one who arises and not the violence?

Comment: @RubioRic: Ah, right. It really is an appalling text for non-scholarly *non-native Anglophones* to be faced with. Even *without* that additional preceding context, I misparsed it myself (I mistakenly understood it as saying ***violence*** arises out of some preceding combination of circumstances, but actually it's the *"**monster**"* that arises). But that monster "personifies" the ***concept*** of "absolute leadership" (what arises is thus an abstract concept; it's not a direct reference to an actual specific "absolute **leader**" who might also "arise").

Comment: ...and to clarify, it's now obvious that the ***double absence*** refers to **1)** the absence of a positive Marxist understanding of the status of their (Marxist's) intellectuals (make of that what you will! :), and **2)**  the lack of a theory of leadership (again, what the heck is that supposed to mean?).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Collins Dictionary

[**arise out**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/arise)

> If something arises from a particular situation, or **arises out** of it,
>   it is created or caused by the situation.

Let me quote part of FumbleFinger's comment

*If "reason" (nounification / personification of the ability of human being to think things through logically) figuratively slumbers, goes to sleep (if people don't use their powers of reasoning)*, this creates the monster of absolute leadership.

As pointed by FumbleFingers such monster *"personifies" the concept of "absolute leadership"*.

More of less the author says that

> Absolute leadership, anti-intellectualism, bureaucratism and violence
>   are caused by a lack of reasoning.